# Is it ok to answer a closed question on the question which it links too even if they are not really the same question?

Tags: discussion

So I have this issue where I want to answer a closed question, but of course, the question being closed, I can't do that. So the next best option seems to be to answer the question which it is supposidely a duplicate of. The problem is that my answer is not really an answer to that question. What should I do in such a situation (in general)?

My specific case is that I want to answer this question:
[How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string)

While the question of which it is supposidely a duplicate is:
[How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables-in-python/)

Which is obviously not the same question. I answered the first question in the second, which a note saying I am actually answering the first question, but I dont really know if that is proper, and what is the best solution.
My answer:
[How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables-in-python/40384282#40384282)

Comment: You could edit the closed question to highlight the actual issue.

Comment: Thanks ... yes I guess I could ... I was hoping there might be a less confrontational approach ;)

Comment: @servy OP didn't ask the question, so the issue can be more tricky.

Comment: @Braiam None of the options mentioned in the answers require you to be the author of the question.

Comment: @Servy well, how can you edit a question highlighting the differences between both in a way that it won't get rejected by reviewers? As I said, it's more tricky.

Comment: @Braiam By clicking the "edit" button and clarifying *the existing content* in a clearer way than the original post.  It's not really more tricky than it is for the author.  And even if it were a bit harder, it still doesn't change the answer to the question.  THe duplicate lists the options available to you, and they all apply to anyone, not just the author.  While you may need to work a bit harder to edit the question effectively if you aren't the author, it doesn't change what options are available to yo.